# How to get SecurityContext in spring security webflux

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

In traditional Spring web applications, it is easy to get a `SecurityContext` from `SecurityContextHolder`, but when I used `spring-security-webflux`(Spring Security 5.0.O.M3) in a spring-webflux application, it seems Spring Security did not store `SecurityContext` into SecurityContextHolder for every requests.

Or in other words, is there an easy way to get current authentication info outside of WebHanlder/Controllers? I wan to implement `AuditorAware` interface to get auditing(auto fills the current user) for Spring Data MongoDB.

**Update**: Spring Security 5.0.0.RELEASE provides a `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` to archive this purpose.

Comment: Similar question here answered by Spring contributor - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793245/how-preauthorize-is-working-in-an-reactive-application-or-how-to-live-without-t . Also see https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/spring-security-5-0-0-m4-released, but in short it seems there is no way currently without reconsidering your design to be reactive.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link of similar questions, and I had also read the spring official blog entries. I had tried the method level annotation for security, but it seems there is no reactive alternative of `SecurityContextHolder` now.

Comment: No, not for now from anything I've seen recently either, and no clear plans for anything. It may required you to consider HOW you audit I suppose, and also maybe whether WebFlux is for you...Web MVC is still viable and is not going away.

Comment: @BrianClozel Thanks for providing this link, it is very helpful to understanding authentication context in a reactive environment. But what I need is how to implement a `AuditorAware` to get auditor filled automatically in mongo documents in a webflux application as it works in generic web applications.  We need another `ReactiveAuditorAware` alternative to simplify the work?

Comment: See https://www.naturalprogrammer.com/blog/16393/spring-security-get-current-user-programmatically