# How @PreAuthorize is working in an Reactive Application or how to live without ThreadLocal?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

Can you explain where the advice handling `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` retrieves the `SecurityContext` in a Reactive application?

The following Spring Security example is a good illustration of this kind of usage: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.0.0.M4/samples/javaconfig/hellowebflux-method

After checking the Spring Security Webflux source code, I've found some implementations of `SecurityContextRepository` but the load method needs the `ServerWebExchange` as a parameter.

I'm trying to understand how to replace `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` call in a standard service (because `ThreadLocal` is no longer an option in a Reactive Application), but I don't understand how to replace this with a call to a `SecurityContextRepository` without a reference on the `ServerWebExchange`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right, `ThreadLocal` is no longer an option because the processing of a request is not tied to a particular thread.

Currently, Spring Security is storing the authentication information as a `ServerWebExchange` attribute, so tied to the current request/response pair. But you still need that information when you don't have direct access to the current exchange, like `@PreAuthorize`.

The authentication information is stored in the Reactive pipeline itself (so accessible from your `Mono` or `Flux`), which is a very interesting Reactor feature - managing a context tied to a particular `Subscriber` (in a web application, the HTTP client is pulling data from the server and acts as such).

I'm not aware of an equivalent of `SecurityContextHolder`, or some shortcut method to get the Authentication information from the context.

See more about [Reactor Context feature in the reference documentation](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context).
You can also see an example of [that being used in Spring Security here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/7fd1cff3ce08263bfc370d011d8eb11b3cd5cfdf/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PrePostAdviceReactiveMethodInterceptor.java#L71-L75).

Answer (score 14):

The [`ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.html) provides the authentication in a reactive way, and is analogous to [`SecurityContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html).

Its [`getContext()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.html#getContext--) method provides a [`Mono<SecurityContext>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html), just like [`SecurityContextHolder.getContext()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html#getContext--) provides a `SecurityContext`.

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder
                    .getContext()
                    .map(context ->
                            context.getAuthentication()
```

Comment: The return Mono / Flux must be returned to Spring (in Controller) for the context to be populated.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented a JwtAuthenticationConverter (kotlin):

```
@Component
class JwtAuthenticationConverter : Function<ServerWebExchange, 
Mono<Authentication>> {

@Autowired
lateinit var jwtTokenUtil: JwtTokenUtil

@Autowired
lateinit var userDetailsService: ReactiveUserDetailsService

private val log = LogFactory.getLog(this::class.java)

override fun apply(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<Authentication> {
    val request = exchange.request

    val token = getJwtFromRequest(request)

    if ( token != null )
        try {
            return userDetailsService.findByUsername(jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(token))
                    .map { UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(it, null, it.authorities) }
        } catch ( e: Exception ) {
            exchange.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
            exchange.response.headers["internal-message"] = e.message
            log.error(e)
        }

    return Mono.empty()
}

private fun getJwtFromRequest(request: ServerHttpRequest): String? {
    val bearerToken = request.headers[SecurityConstants.TOKEN_HEADER]?.first {
        it.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, true)}
    return if (bearerToken.isNullOrBlank()) null else bearerToken?.substring(7, bearerToken.length)
}
```

And then I set a SecurityConfig like this:

```
val authFilter = AuthenticationWebFilter(ReactiveAuthenticationManager {
    authentication: Authentication -> Mono.just(authentication)
})
authFilter.setAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter)

http.addFilterAt( authFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
```

You can use this approach to customize your AuthenticationConverter as I did to jwt based authentication to set the desired authentication object.