# How to make AuditorAware work with Spring Data Mongo Reactive

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor, spring-webflux

Spring Security 5 provides a [`ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` to fetch  the `SecurityContext` from a Reactive context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51133327/545127), but when I want to implement `AuditorAware` and get audition work automatically, but it does not work. **Currently I can not find a `Reactive` variant for `AuditorAware`**.

```
@Bean
public AuditorAware<Username> auditor() {
    return () -> ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
        .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
        .log()
        .filter(a -> a != null && a.isAuthenticated())
        .map(Authentication::getPrincipal)
        .cast(UserDetails.class)
        .map(auth -> new Username(auth.getName()))
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty())
        .blockOptional();
}
```

I have added `@EnableMongoAuduting` on my boot `Application` class.

On the Mongo document class. I added audition related annotations.

```
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime createdDate;

@CreatedBy
private Username author;
```

When I added a post, the `createdDate` is filled, but author is null.

```
{"id":"5a49ccdb9222971f40a4ada1","title":"my first post","content":"content of my first post","createdDate":"2018-01-01T13:53:31.234","author":null}
```

The complete codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-springboot2-sample/tree/master/server), based on Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7.

**Update:** Spring Boot 2.4.0-M2/Spring Data Common 2.4.0-M2/Spring Data Mongo 3.1.0-M2 includes a `ReactiveAuditorAware`, Check [this new sample](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/boot-data-mongo-auditing), **Note**: use `@EnableReactiveMongoAuditing` to activiate it.

Comment: There's no auditing support yet for reactive use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Deprecated: see the update solution in the original post

Before the official **reactive** AuditAware is provided, there is an alternative to implement these via Spring Data Mongo specific `ReactiveBeforeConvertCallback`.

1. Do not use `@EnableMongoAuditing`
2. Implement your own  `ReactiveBeforeConvertCallback`, here I use a `PersistentEntity` interface for those entities that need to be audited.

```java
public class PersistentEntityCallback implements ReactiveBeforeConvertCallback<PersistentEntity> {

    @Override
    public Publisher<PersistentEntity> onBeforeConvert(PersistentEntity entity, String collection) {
        var user = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .filter(it -> it != null && it.isAuthenticated())
                .map(Authentication::getPrincipal)
                .cast(UserDetails.class)
                .map(userDetails -> new Username(userDetails.getUsername()))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty());

        var currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        if (entity.getId() == null) {
            entity.setCreatedDate(currentTime);
        }
        entity.setLastModifiedDate(currentTime);

        return user
                .map(u -> {
                            if (entity.getId() == null) {
                                entity.setCreatedBy(u);
                            }
                            entity.setLastModifiedBy(u);

                            return entity;
                        }
                )
                .defaultIfEmpty(entity);
    }
}
```

Check the complete codes [here](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PersistentEntityCallback.java).

Comment: This might not work if a code supports insert/update through the same endpoint and db save method. If someone would send a DTO with id which would get mapped into a constructed DOCUMENT and it does not exist in a database, all the id dependent fields will be empty.

Comment: Check the complete codes please, the solution I posted does not care your DTO, just track the document you are operating on.

Comment: The problem is that if the constructed entity has already assigned ID but it does not exist in database, your solution will not work i guess. I am missing here some routine to check repository if the ID exists.

Comment: You can add the logic to satisfy your business right? Personally, I have been always using Spring Data to generate the ID. Or share your workable solution as an extra answer, it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting another solution which counts with input id to support update operations:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuditCallback implements ReactiveBeforeConvertCallback<AuditableEntity> {

    private final ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    private Mono<?> exists(Object id, Class<?> entityClass) {
        if (id == null) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        return mongoTemplate.findById(id, entityClass);
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<AuditableEntity> onBeforeConvert(AuditableEntity entity, String collection) {
        var securityContext = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        return securityContext
                .zipWith(exists(entity.getId(), entity.getClass()))
                .map(tuple2 -> {
                    var auditableEntity = (AuditableEntity) tuple2.getT2();
                    auditableEntity.setLastModifiedBy(tuple2.getT1().getAuthentication().getName());
                    auditableEntity.setLastModifiedDate(Instant.now());
                    return auditableEntity;
                })
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.zip(securityContext, Mono.just(entity))
                        .map(tuple2 -> {
                            var auditableEntity = (AuditableEntity) tuple2.getT2();
                            String principal = tuple2.getT1().getAuthentication().getName();
                            Instant now = Instant.now();
                            auditableEntity.setLastModifiedBy(principal);
                            auditableEntity.setCreatedBy(principal);
                            auditableEntity.setLastModifiedDate(now);
                            auditableEntity.setCreatedDate(now);
                            return auditableEntity;
                        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To have createdBy attribute filled, you need to link your auditorAware bean with the annotation @EnableMongoAuditing

In your MongoConfig class, define your bean :

```
@Bean(name = "auditorAware")
public AuditorAware<String> auditor() {
    ....
}
```

and use it in the annotation :

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing(auditorAwareRef="auditorAware")
class MongoConfig {
    ....
}
```

Comment: There's no auditing support yet for reactive use. Currently, auditors are pulled from `ThreadLocal` which isn't applicable for reactive use because of  constant thread switching and deferred execution.

Comment: @RichardSinelle Did you try this auditing feature in a **reactive** application?

Comment: I start to implement a prototype inspired by the code you provide, thanks. The bean is a SimpleReactiveMongoRepository. I keep you up to date