# How to use Mongo Auditing and a UUID as id with Spring Boot 2.2.x?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to have Documents stored with an UUID id and createdAt / updatedAt fields. My solution was working with Spring Boot 2.1.x. After I upgraded from Spring Boot 2.1.11.RELEASE to 2.2.0.RELEASE my test for MongoAuditing failed with `createdAt = null`. What do I need to do to get the createdAt field filled again?

This is not just a testproblem. I ran the application and it has the same behaviour as my test. All auditing fields stay null.

I have a Configuration to enable MongoAuditing and UUID generation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public GenerateUUIDListener generateUUIDListener() {
        return new GenerateUUIDListener();
    }
}
```

The listner hooks into the `onBeforeConvert` - I guess thats where the trouble starts.

```
public class GenerateUUIDListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<IdentifiableEntity> {
    @Override
    public void onBeforeConvert(BeforeConvertEvent<IdentifiableEntity> event) {
        IdentifiableEntity entity = event.getSource();
        if (entity.isNew()) {
            entity.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        }
    }
}
```

The document itself (I dropped the getter and setters):

```
@Document
public class MyDocument extends InsertableEntity {
    private String name;
}


public abstract class InsertableEntity extends IdentifiableEntity {
    @CreatedDate
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant createdAt;
}

public abstract class IdentifiableEntity implements Persistable<UUID> {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isNew() {
        return getId() == null;
    }
}
```

A complete minimal example can be find here (including a test) https://github.com/mab/auditable
With 2.1.11.RELEASE the test succeeds with 2.2.0.RELEASE it fails.

Comment: The execution order of the `BeforeConvertEvent` seems to be changed. With 2.2.0 the id is set first and then `isNew` is failing for checking if `createdAt` needs to be set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me the best solution was to switch from event UUID generation to a callback based one. With the implementation of `Ordered` we can set the new callback to be executed after the `AuditingEntityCallback`.

```
public class IdEntityCallback implements BeforeConvertCallback<IdentifiableEntity>, Ordered {
    @Override
    public IdentifiableEntity onBeforeConvert(IdentifiableEntity entity, String collection) {
      if (entity.isNew()) {
        entity.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
      }
      return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
      return 101;
    }
}
```

I registered the callback with the `MongoConfiguration`. For a more general solution you might want to take a look at the registration of the `AuditingEntityCallback` with the `MongoAuditingBeanDefinitionParser.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public IdEntityCallback registerCallback() {
    return new IdEntityCallback();
  }
}
```

Comment: or `implements ReactiveBeforeConvertCallback` on the reactive stack

Comment: However, if using the reactive stack, skip `@EnableMongoAuditing` as there is currently no reactive interface for `AuditorAware`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62151824/1098564

Answer (score 1):

`MongoTemplate` works in the following way on `doInsert()`

- `this.maybeEmitEvent` - emit an **event** (`onBeforeConvert`, `onBeforeSave` and such) so any `AbstractMappingEventListener` can catch and act upon like you did with `GenerateUUIDListener`
- `this.maybeCallBeforeConvert` - call before convert **callbacks** like `mongo auditing`

like you can see in source code of `MongoTemplate.class` src (831-832)

```
protected <T> T doInsert(String collectionName, T objectToSave, MongoWriter<T> writer) {
        BeforeConvertEvent<T> event = new BeforeConvertEvent(objectToSave, collectionName);
        T toConvert = ((BeforeConvertEvent)this.maybeEmitEvent(event)).getSource(); //emit event
        toConvert = this.maybeCallBeforeConvert(toConvert, collectionName); //call some before convert handlers
        ...
}
```

`MongoAudit` marks `createdAt` only to new entities by checking if `entity.isNew() == true`

because your code (UUID) already set the `Id` the `createdAt` is not populated (the entity is not considered new)

you can do the following (order by best to worst):

- forget about the `UUID` and use `String` for your id, let the mongo itself create and manage it's entities ids (this how `MongoTemplate` actually works lines 811-812)
- keep the `UUID` at the code level, convert from/to `String` when inserting and retrieving from the db
- create a custom repository like in this [post](https://craftingjava.com/blog/custom-document-id-spring-data-mongodb/)
- stay with `2.1.11.RELEASE`
- set the `updateAt` by `GenerateUUIDListener` as well as `id` (rename it `NewEntityListener` or smth), basically implement the audit
- implement a **new** `isNew()` logic that don't depends only on the entity `id`

> in version `2.1.11.RELEASE` the order of the methods was flipped (`MongoTemplate.class` 804-805) so your code worked fine

as an abstract approach, the nature of event is to be sort of send-and-forget (async compatible), so it's a very bad practice to change the object itself, there is **NO** grantee for order of computation, if any

this is why the audit build on **callbacks** and not **events**, and that's why Pivotal don't (need to) keep order between versions

Comment: Thank you for your detailed post. I need to keep UUIDs. The suggestion with having a string in the database is the current implementation. That does not solve anything. The important point for me is to not rely on events. I have a look in to implement a custom repository.